# How do I access iCloud Container data from an app with a different Bundle Identifier?

Tags: xcode, icloud, cloudkit, entitlements

I am finishing an app that allows users to submit feedback to an iCloud Container. In order to simplify the process of retrieving that feedback, and to protect privacy, I have created another app to read those submissions. This app will be private and not uploaded to the App Store. This requires that both apps be able to access the same iCloud Container. Therefore, both apps have entitlements with their iCloud Container identifier set to the same value:

**iCloud.com.myDomain.My-App**

For clarity I refer to the first app as **My App** and the second as **My App Feedback**.

When I try and run My App Feedback to read the feedback, Xcode gives an error:

**Couldn't get container configuration from the server for container "iCloud.com.myDomain.My-App-Feedback"**

It appears that even though I have set the app entitlements iCloud Container identifier for both apps to **My App**, Xcode is using the app Bundle Identifier instead.

Is there a way to override that behavior so that both apps can access the iCloud data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have selected the correct container in the entitlements, then just make sure when you set your CloudKit Container in code from within **My App Feedback** that you are specifying the correct one:

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.myDomain.My-App")
```

and **not** either of these:

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.myDomain.My-App-Feedback")
let container = CKContainer.default() //This should work, but might be using the wrong one
```

You could confirm which container is being selected by printing it to the console when it gets instantiated. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Funny I had to go all the way to StackOverflow when you are on my local Slack group!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.name_of_your_container")` instead of `CKContainer.default()`

I named my Cloudkit container `testapp` and my app's bundle id was `com.my_team_name.testapp`. When running Cloudkit queries, I kept getting this error:

`Couldn't get container configuration from the server for container "iCloud.com.my_team_name.testapp"`

After looking at the Cloudkit Dashboard I realized that my container's name was literally only "testapp."

Changed my code to `CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.testapp")`. Worked just fine.